# Postgres subscription is not enabling

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am on cluster of postgresql server where we get user for time limit, there is one already created subscription show it disabled, I want to enable it, but it is created by other user, even I become superuser but it is not enabled by using following command

```
ALTER SUBSCRIPTION mysub ENABLE;
```

I get following error

```
ERROR:  must be owner of subscription wildcards
```

I changed my role to superuser but it still can't enable it. How can I enable this service, as I suspect it was disable due to up-gradation of slave from postgresql 11 to 12 version. What roles are usally required to ENABLE subscriptions. I am using `SET ROLE` command to be superuser. Do I need to run ALTER USER command?

Comment: Any superuser can do that. Either you are not really a superuser, or you are not using standard PostgreSQL.

Comment: I am using command ```SET ROLE RDS_SUPERUSER``` but still getting must be owner of subscription.

Comment: That user is no superuser, *and* you are not using PostgreSQL. I'll remove the PostgreSQL tag.

Comment: It is Postgresql version 12 on AWS

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe you changed tag and removed Posgresql tag so seem I won't get any response. any how thank you.

Comment: But this question is not about PostgreSQL. Adding the PostgreSQL tag would only confuse. Perhaps you should ask Amazon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a lot things and wasting two days I got following method. First in my subscription user name is visible so use following command to change user.

```
grant {your_user_name} role to current_user
```

Now connect to that DB and Alter your subscription but instead of Enable you have to delete and recreate it, but remember you must have master credentials. This work and these all are commands of postgresql and I got help from its documentation, I don't know why it aws rds postgres is not postgresql.